# Create a location on my Mac where iCloud will not be used

Tags: icloud

I am using iCloud on my mac. I am wildly uncomfortable that it sees the Documents and Desktop folder in my account.

Can I create a folder or folders myself where iCloud will not be used?

Comment: The default is not to use iCloud so you have to explicitly turn it on to put those directories in the cloud. You can just create a directoy in your home directory otherwise. I think you need to explain how you turned icloud on.

Comment: iCloud doesn't 'see' your files. (Any more than it 'sees' all your passwords, contacts, events, etc). But it lets you access them from any of your devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either

- turn off iCloud storage for Documents and Deskop in System Preferences

or

- create a new folder "Local Documents" in your home folder for documents you don't want to syncronize with iCloud